# RxJS: what is bufferSize in shareReplay?

Tags: rxjs

I don't understand what `bufferSize` parameter means and what does it effect.

What are the differences between the following?

```
var published = source
    .shareReplay();

var published = source
    .shareReplay(0)

var published = source
    .shareReplay(1);

var published = source
    .shareReplay(10);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md and http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html. What is it specifically that you don't understand? It is not hard to experiment though. Try the code you wrote and ask specific questions about what you find strange. As is it is hard to answer this question without repeating the documentation.

Comment: I tried to experiment bu didn't see the difference. And yes I dont understand what is "Maximum element count of the replay buffer." What is this buffer?

Comment: Post your experimentation, it will be easier to comment on it. From the reactivexio documentation : `bufferSize` -
the maximum number of items to buffer and replay to subsequent observers. Basically, `replay(X)` keeps the last X elements in a buffer, and when a new subcriber comes in, it gives it immediately those values in the same order they were produced (hence the replay semantics).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
source     --1--2--3--4--5--6--7
subscriber -----------S---------
```

with `source.shareReplay(2)` `subscriber` will get `[2, 3, 4, 5,...]`

Comment: Thank you for noting what helped you. It would help others with the same question if you would also copy the explanation information in the Comments that help lead you to this understanding, with attribution(s) to the person(s) who provided the information. Comments tend to be volatile and not as "obvious" as the information in the Q&A :-)

Comment: Can you please explain why the subscriber gets [2, 3, 4, 5, ...]

Comment: Because it subscribes at the moment when share stream emits 4, as there shareReplay(2), stream will replay for it 2 previous values 2 and 3

Comment: Oh, i see. The brackets made me think it would emit an array. In other words, a subscriber would "2" and "3" (the last 2 values before the current value) plus the last value emitted (so the last 3 values). After that it would also receive any future emissions.

Answer (score 13):

**BufferSize :**

- BufferSize means the number of items cached and replayed
- On subscribe, It will replays a specific number of emissions
- Items stayed Cached, even after there is no subscribers

**Coming to Question :**

```
var published = source
    .shareReplay();
```

any subscriber to this will get all the items/stream of data emitted by source

```
var published = source
    .shareReplay(0)
```

It will cache last emitted value

```
var published = source
    .shareReplay(1);
```

It will cache last emitted value, same like above

```
var published = source
    .shareReplay(10);
```

It will cache the last 10 items emitted by source.

**More Information :**
I'm going to explain this concept with one example.

```
 let source$ = interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    take(5),
    shareReplay(3)
  )
source$.subscribe(res => console.log('1st time=>', res))

setTimeout(() => {
  source$.subscribe(res => console.log('2nd time=>', res))
}, 5000)
```

Note: Here first subscription just mean to start emitting the values. It will emit values five times as I m using **take** operator to limit the emission **interval**
It will lead to output :

```
1st time=> 0
1st time=> 1
1st time=> 2
1st time=> 3 
1st time=> 4
```

Now Just focus on second observable : as we can see the bufferSize value is set to 3, so It will log last three emitted values

```
2nd time=> 2
2nd time=> 3
2nd time=> 4
```