# shareReplay: can I reset or set the buffer size to 0 so that new subriptions have to wait for a new emit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following observable:

```
this.roles$ = auth.User$
            .pipe(tap((val: JwtUser|null) => this.logger.debug('Session updated, updating permissions %o', val)))
            .pipe(switchMap(this.getRoles.bind(this)))
            .pipe(shareReplay({refCount: true, bufferSize: 1}));
```

The getRoles() method performs a HTTP request every time the User$ emits. The last fetched value is replayed to all new subscriptions. When the User$ emits, however, I do not want subscriptions to get the last value. Instead, I want them to wait for the newly fetched one. I thought I could achieve this by resetting/clearing the buffer whenever User$ emits, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there an other approach I could try or a way to achieve this one?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `skip(1)` for subscriptions where you don't want the cached value. However, this might skip the first emission if the cache is empty.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: 'User$ emits, however, I do not want subscriptions to get the last value. Instead, I want them to wait for the newly fetched one'; isn't 'last value' === 'newly fetched one' ? As far as I know, then the source(`User$`) emits, the `ReplaySubject` in use will pass the value along to its registered subscribers(existing subscriptions).

Comment: The problem is when a new subscription occurs when the User$ has already emitted a new value, but the getRoles has not yet returned. This subscription will get the outdated roles and that is not ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, you actually like a buffer size of 0. However, `shareReplay(0)` emits the last value of the source like `shareReplay(1)` does (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60912724/1065654) explanation of `shareReplay`). You can use `share` and a dummy subscriber instead:

```
this.roles$ = auth.User$
            .pipe(tap((val: JwtUser|null) => this.logger.debug('Session updated, updating permissions %o', val)))
            .pipe(switchMap(this.getRoles.bind(this)))
            .pipe(share());
// keep `refCount` above 0 using a dummy subscription
this.roles$.subscribe(() => {});
```

Please let me know via a comment if this meets your requirements.

Comment: I have indeed circumvented the issue in a similar manner. Thank for the reply!